# FFMPEG command for automatic video splitting and thumbnail creation

Tags: ffmpeg, split

I am trying to write an FFMPEG command that:

- takes as **input** a video *input.mp4* and an image *pic.jpg*
- As an **output** splits *input.mp4* into 20-second videos, renaming them in order; for each split video, it creates a thumbnail image, by copying *pic.jpg*, writing on it the corresponding order number, and saving it with the same order number as a name.

To make an example, here is what the folder should contain after running the script:

```
input.mp4 <-- video to be splitted
pic.jpg <-- Base for thumbnail

[0].mp4 <-- first 20 seconds of input.mp4
[0].jpg <-- thumbnail image with "0" printed on

[1].mp4 <-- second 20 seconds of input.mp4
[1].jpg <-- thumbnail image with "1" printed on

... and so on
```

This is my command for now:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i pic.jpg -f segment -segment_time 20 -map 0:a -map 0:v -vcodec copy -reset_timestamps 1 output[%d].mp4 -map 1:v -vf "drawtext=text=%d:fontcolor=white:fontsize=75:x=1002:y=100:" pic[%d].jpeg
```

but gives multiple problems:

- `%d` is not recognized by `drawtext` (it says *stray % before d*)
- If I remove `%d` from drawtext (substituting it with `'Exampletext'`), the script splits correctly the video, but creates only *pic[1].jpg*, without anything written on it. No other .jpg files seem to be created.

**Notice**
I can't use bash scripts or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr - no can do. It may be possible in 3 steps.

> %d is not recognized by drawtext (it says stray % before d)

As it shouldn't be. Nowhere in its documentation talks about it supporting c-printf format strings.

> If I remove %d from drawtext (substituting it with 'Exampletext'), the script splits correctly the video, but creates only pic[1].jpg, without anything written on it. No other .jpg files seem to be created.

This is expected behavior as the `pic.jpg` input stream dies after 1 frame (because it's a still picture = only 1 frame long). You can loop the input image (look up `image2` demuxer documentation) but you must know the number of segments you are going to produce ahead of the time (not to mention it's a moot point because the intended `drawtext` operation is a no go).

The only workaround I can think of is to do this in 3 steps:

1. call FFmpeg to do the `segment` job
2. count the number of segments created, and create a subtitle file (.srt would suffice). Each segment count to occupy 1 second each.
3. call FFmpeg again with `pic.jpg` input, looping it to produce the matching number of frames to the number of segments at 1-fps framerate. Use `subtitle` filter to burn in the segment numbers specified in the subtitle.

Obviously, doing the above automatically in a script makes a lot of sense, but the above could be done manually with a lot less effort than numbering each thumbnail individually.